# Finding Matches between two columns of different files and printing it out a different column

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I was trying to figure out how to see if there were any matches between column 2 of `file1` and column 6 of `file2`. If so, I wanted that match printed along with the respective string in column 14 of `file2`, saved onto a different file, `file3`.

file1:

```
  1 ENSCAFT00000037911
  1 ENSCAFT00000046425
  1 ENSC
  1 ENSCAFT00000009252
  1 ENSCAFT00000049028
  1 ENSC
  2 AFT00000000014
  2 ENSCAFT00000042968
  2 ENSCAFT000000
```

file2:

```
   1 13336837 13358107 -1 SERPINB7 AFT00000000014 ENSCAFG00000023436 34.51 13.70 16.30 7.80 18.85 10.21 0.50 
   1 14028702 14130819 -1 PHLPP1 ENSCAFT00000000123 ENSCAFG00000000070 1531.81 1090.63 518.08 559.90 581.70 1126.21 0.41 
   1 14702158 14789303 1 PIGN ENSCAFT00000000137 ENSCAFG00000000083 979.07 882.88 296.70 272.97 369.74 877.13 0.31 
   1 17154193 17210961 -1 ZNF532 ENSCAFT00000049028 ENSCAFG00000000103 31.62 58.98 13.83 23.80 27.50 15.38 0.42 
   1 17154246 17210961 -1 NA ENSCAFT00000000164 ENSCAFG00000000103 31.62 58.98 13.83 23.80 27.50 15.38 0.42 
   1 17491358 17563171 1 ALPK2 ENSCAFT00000000169 ENSCAFG00000000107 12.18 10.55 39.99 31.41 210.85 15.82 3.14 
   1 18214832 18277601 1 ATP8B1 ENSCAFT00000000203 ENSCAFG00000000123 751.98 827.35 373.91 394.89 571.98 711.16 0.49
```

Desired Output:

```
    ENSCAFT00000049028 0.42
    AFT00000000014 0.50
```

The order does not matter.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know about that. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with `join`:

```
join -1 2 -2 6 -o 1.2,2.14 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k6 file2 )
```

- `-1 2` defines that in `file1` field 2 is the join field.
- `-2 6` defines that in `file2` field 6 is the join field.
- `-o 1.2,2.14` is the output format `file1` field 2 followed by `file2` field 14.
- `<(sort ...)` the two files must be sorted at the join field `-k` for `join` to work properly.

---

Or with `awk` (doesn't need a sorted input):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0} FNR!=NR&&a[$6]{print $6,$14}' file1 file2
```

- `FNR==NR` applies to the first file  `file1`:

  - `a[$2]=$0` fills the `a` array with the 2nd field `$2` as index.
- `FNR!=NR` applies to the second file `file2`:
- `a[$6]` if the 6th field `$6` is present in the array `a`.

  - `print $6,$14` print the two values.

Comment: I've been using the join method and it works like a charm! Thank you so much!